# Flutter Form disappears when keyboard shows

Tags: dart, flutter

I've created a `Form` with Flutter but when I focus on a field and the keyboard pops up the content disappears.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:greencat/greencat.dart';
import 'package:woody_app/Application.dart';
import 'package:woody_app/actions/AuthAction.dart';
import 'package:woody_app/states/AuthState.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new ProfileScreenState();
}


class PersonData {
  String name = '';
  String phoneNumber = '';
  String password = '';
}

class ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  final Store<AuthState, AuthAction<dynamic>> _store = Application.get().store;
  StreamSubscription<AuthState> _subscriber;

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  PersonData person = new PersonData();

  void showInSnackBar(String value) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
        content: new Text(value)
    ));
  }

  bool _autovalidate = false;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  void _handleSubmitted() {
    final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (!form.validate()) {
      _autovalidate = true;  // Start validating on every change.
      showInSnackBar('Please fix the errors in red before submitting.');
    } else {
      form.save();
      showInSnackBar('${person.name}\'s phone number is ${person.phoneNumber}');
    }
  }

  String _validateName(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty)
      return 'Name is required.';
    final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r'^[A-za-z ]+$');
    if (!nameExp.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Please enter only alphabetical characters.';
    return null;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _subscriber = _store.stream.listen((AuthState state) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscriber.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(child: new Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidate: _autovalidate,
        child: new ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                hintText: 'What do people call you?',
                labelText: 'Name *',
              ),
              onSaved: (String value) {
                person.name = value;
              },
              validator: _validateName,
            ),
            new Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              alignment: const FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.5),
              child: new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('SUBMIT'),
                onPressed: _handleSubmitted,
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: new Text('* indicates required field', style: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .caption),
            ),
          ],
        )
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be running into [10826](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10826).

Comment: Yes, but I cant get the workaround to work..

Comment: try a longer delay

Comment: So I have to wait a little longer for a fix?

Comment: There's a delay timer in the workaround, you can use a larger number. Fix should be coming soon though.

Comment: I don't really understand you reply, but I've found https://gist.github.com/collinjackson/50172e3547e959cba77e2938f2fe5ff5 but I can't get it to work. My current widget stack is: Container -> SingleChildScrollView -> Column -> Container (from this widget it's an custom widget) -> Form -> Column -> EnsureVisibleWhenFocused

Comment: I've faced the same recently, found working solution [here](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/hint-4-ensure-a-textfield-or-textformfield-is-visible-in-the-viewport-when-has-the-focus/) Hope flutter devs will fix it eventually, but for now, even in the flutter examples it does not work properly

Answer (score 9):

try this below in your Scafold()

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout if you are nesting Scaffolds. Each Scaffold adds an extra space between the keyboard and the UI elements. For checking if this is the case, set the Scaffold's property "resizeToAvoidBottomPadding" to false and see the effect

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your widget tree inside a SingleChildScrollView() and whenever you will select a TextField, you can scroll it up to see it.